# Shopify Section load event in Liquid file (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, themes, liquid

I am Shopify developer. I designed a slideshow using Flickity library in Shopify. My slider working fine on URL when load but it's not work on Shopify Theme Editor, till I am not saved the design. after save design is working fine.

I am using this script in section file it's not working but when I paste this code in theme.liquid file it's working fine on both sides.

I don't want like this image

[image]

```
<script>
  {% if request.design_mode %}
        console.log("123");
        document.addEventListener("shopify:section:load", function() {
        console.log("abc");
        var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
            var flkty = new Flickity( elem, {
                autoPlay: "{{ section.settings.autoplay_slide }}", 
                pageDots: true, 
                contain: true, 
                wrapAround: false, 
                imagesLoaded: true, 
                accessibility: false
            });
        });
      {% endif %}
</script>
```

I want, that when i select section from theme editor it's working smoothly.

I want like this image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `shopify:section:load` **which fires only inside the theme editor** (that's why you can't get it working outside of theme editor), you should include this `<script>` tag in the end of your section's code and change it a bit:

```html
<script>
  {% if request.design_mode %}
        console.log("123");
        let flkty; // for later use
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // run this script after window is ready and scripts are loaded
            console.log("abc");
            var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
            if (elem) { // check if element was found before using it
                 flkty = new Flickity( elem, {
                    autoPlay: "{{ section.settings.autoplay_slide }}", 
                    pageDots: true, 
                    contain: true, 
                    wrapAround: false, 
                    imagesLoaded: true, 
                    accessibility: false
                 });
             }
        });
      {% endif %}
</script>
```

Comment: I used this code but the results are same.

Comment: Can you share a link so we can reproduce an issue?

Comment: Can i only share full section code with you? because the issue is in the editor. And I have no permission to share store details. but the link is https://practice-store-21.myshopify.com/ and password is: "admin123"

Comment: The <script> tag is empty because {{ request.design_mode }} is false. What is this variable? EDIT: Returns true if the request is being made from the theme editor in the Shopify admin. You need to remove that if statement

Comment: Please let me know one thing that this script can worked in section code?? because this same code work in theme.liquid but not in section code

Comment: Slider works for me but the discussed script is not rendered by liquid because request.design_mode is false. You need to remove it

Comment: yes I removed. but same results

Comment: image showing up-down